# Как лучше представить игральные карты в базе данных?

Tags: база-данных

Посоветуйте, как лучше представить игральные карты в базе данных: в виде чисел или строковых константах?

```
create table Card(
    Id int identity(0,1) primary key,

    Suit varchar(15) not null,
    Rank varchar(15) not null,
);
```

Я пока сделал так, но все-таки интересно мнение тех, кто имеет больший опыт работы с базами данных.

Comment: Целыми, конечно, зачем тут строки? И при чём здесь identity?

Comment: Числами кодировать хорошо, но приходиться тогда где-то документировать, что это число означает.

Comment: Если у вас проблемы на таком уровне - лучше и числа записывать прописью :)

Comment: Какие проблемы? Нет никаких проблем. Просто интересно мнение и советы людей. Вы же когда пишите код на каком-нибудь языке, вы же не используете числа в качестве параметров, а используете перечесляемый тип. Вот и сдесь такая же ситуация.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю ни вашей задачи, ни используемой СУБД, но, суть в целом ясна: вы хотите хранить информацию об игральных картах в БД. В таком случае, нет ничего особенного: почему бы просто не пронумеровать все карты от 0 до 14 и хранить их в виде цифр таким образом? Это и памяти меньше займет и удобнее будет( не будет привязанности к разговорным языкам ), так что впоследствии это дело можно будет и локализировать без проблем.

Comment: Это очень хорошая идея, но когда я обдумывал это решение раньше, я принял во внимание тот факт, что это будет не читабельно, и если другой человек будет поддержывать и модифицировать код, то ему будет тяжело понять, что эта цифра означает

Comment: "если другой человек будет поддержывать и модифицировать код, то ему будет тяжело понять, что эта цифра означает" комментарии к коду спасут отца русской демократии!

Comment: Так предполагается, что новый человек не в состоянии прочитать,  осмыслить и запомнить одну строчку: "номинал карт представлен значениями от X до Y" :) Ну и в коде, видимо, все номиналы будут в виде magic number...

Comment: код должен самодокументируемым )

Comment: Ну дык чем сложно понять `if( card_value == CARD_ACE && card_suit == SUIT_HEARTS )`?